# User limit to use firebird sql.dll database in b2b application

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, firebird, b2b

I am developing a b2b application. Is there a limit on the number of user logins to a database when using a b2b application that will integrate with FirebirdClient.dll?

Answer (score 0):

Official limits on Firebird server are published as 
https://www.firebirdsql.org/en/firebird-technical-specifications/
There is no any intended limits on number of connections.

However, every connection occupies some OS-level resources, for example:

- TCP port, when TCP/IP connection to server is used (most typical case)
- OS-level process (when Classic Server edition/mode of Firebird is used)
- OS-level thread  (when SuperServer edition/mode is used)
- Memory (for connection-unique and shared DB caches, locking maps, etc)

Those OS-level resources would almost certainly get exhausted much earlier than any Firebird-internal limits.

> with FirebirdClient.dll?

I do not know this library, so perhaps it may impose its own limitations on top of Firebird ones, consult the lib's documentation or maintainers.

UPD. Firebird Core developer answered (most probably refering current FB version 3) at http://www.sql.ru/forum/actualutils.aspx?action=gotomsg&tid=523729&msg=20809882

Depending upon connection protocol, there are following limits on number of connections:

- XNET (local) - no explicit limit
- Embedded DLL/SO library - no explicit limit
- WNET (Microsoft Named Pipes) - 255 connections, as limited by API itself
- INET (TCP/IP) - 2048 simultaneous open sockets (for both events connections and data connections in total), as hardcoded in Firebird

Using Classic Server and SuperClassic (but NOT SuperServer) configuration/edition one can launch several TCP/IP listeners on different TCP/IP ports, multiplying the 2048 limit (however clients should be aware there are several different ports to try to connect to)

Comment: SuperServer on Windows has a max of 1024 connections in FB 2.5 and earlier and 2048 in 3.0. Although imho you're doing something wrong if you need more than a few dozen connections concurrently.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel was it documented anywhere but some magic constants in sources?

Comment: Not sure, the change in Firebird 3 is documented in the [release notes](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/release_notes/html/en/3_0/bk02ch03s05.html#d0e2712), and it also applies to SuperClassic

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Vlad answered in forum. If u have Jira password at hands, could u set DOCS ticket for updating "Technical Limitations" page ?